# how can I make name to react routes to use it in links?

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5

I cannot find analog of Laravel's routing style in React js

```
Route::get('/categories', 'MenuItemController@getCategories')->name('getting-categories');
```

Here has component: ->name()
Laravel Developers able use it in view like so:

```
<a href={{ route(getting-categories) }}>some link</a>
```

After the code link looks like:

```
<a href="/categories">some link</a>
```

If react has not similar functionality, help me to make a similar one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have one suggestion..
If you use React Router, you could have a look on this page: 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config

If you have the routes configured in an array like this, then you could easily add another key for the `name` in the route data and write a function which takes the `path` based on your `name`

Comment: thank you very much :-) Your link is deciding my problem.